# Why does adding TOP 10 to DISTINCT SELECT timeout when DISTINCT SELECT does not?

Tags: sql-server

When I run a basic `SELECT DISTINCT` query (NOTE: this occurs only when using a `View` not a `Table`)

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    [DateField]
FROM MyData
```

I quickly (< 1 sec) get my 190 rows back. But when I add `TOP 10` (either before or after the `DISTINCT`) it runs until it times out (5 minutes +).

```
SELECT TOP 10 DISTINCT 
    [DateField]
FROM MyData
```

This also happens if I put the `SELECT DISTINCT` query as a subquery (just testing alternatives).

```
SELECT TOP 10 
   FOO.[DateField] 
FROM
     (SELECT DISTINCT  [DateField]
      FROM MyData) FOO
```

Here is a sample of the data returned by the `SELECT DISTINCT` query.

```
DateField
2016-12-01 00:00:00.000
2016-09-01 00:00:00.000
2016-11-01 00:00:00.000
2017-11-29 00:00:00.000
2017-07-01 00:00:00.000
2016-08-01 00:00:00.000
2017-04-24 00:00:00.000
2016-03-01 00:00:00.000
2017-03-01 00:00:00.000
2016-07-01 00:00:00.000
2016-02-01 00:00:00.000
2016-04-01 00:00:00.000
2017-01-01 00:00:00.000
2016-06-01 00:00:00.000
2016-05-01 00:00:00.000
2018-02-28 00:00:00.000
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does comparing the execution plan for the two queries tell you?

Comment: NOTE: the above queries were run on a View not on a Table. This issue does not happen when I run the queries on a Table.

Comment: Then edit your post and put that information in it where it can be seen. But again, what do the execution plans tell you?

Comment: @KenWhite, I can't edit my question as I don't have a high enough Rep, so added the extra information in the comments.

Comment: You can always edit your own questions and answers. If you have enough rep to post the question, you have the rep needed to edit it. The details belong in the question itself, not buried in comments. Click the [edit] link below the tags (or the one I just gave you in this comment).

Comment: If I am reading the Execution plans correctly (which is a big IF as I didn't know about them until now) the time hit is coming from Nested Loops (Inner Joins). Potentially because the View contains a number of joins. Not really sure.

Comment: Sounds like the view is the problem

Comment: See execution plan, there you can see where is problem. If you not see add to your question execution plan with `TOP 10` and without it

Comment: Not that specifying `top 10` without specifying an `ORDER BY` clause is almost always nonsense. Does the query time improve if you actually give the server something sensible to do (i.e. apply an `ORDER BY` clause as well)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever adding ORDER BY worked. Including this in the query meant it returned in <1 sec. Thanks for the tip!!